# is binary file(pdf, word, excel, ppt, mp3,...) download possible using XHR or fetch?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, download, xmlhttprequest

is binary file(pdf, word, excel, ppt, mp3,...) download possible using XHR or fetch? I have seen some snippets and tricks for pdf and images using data URI and base64 conversion. Do we have some better mechanism available?

I need to download a file with following constraints:

1. File download request must be authenticated using an oauth2 token. Essentially it means that I need to set the Authorization header to some value
2. Server returns chunked data. Need to join the chunks (or can I force server to send non-chunked data)

**My NodeJS Code**

*For getting metadata*

```
var options = {
        hostname : API_HOST ,
        method : 'GET',
        port : 443,
        path : API_PATH + fileId,
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN
        }
    }

    var meta = '';
    var fileRequest = https.request(options, function(response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            meta += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function(error) {
            callback(error, meta);
        })
    });
```

*For getting actual file*

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(GDRIVE_ROOT + '\\' + JSON.parse(meta).originalFilename);
        var options = {
            hostname : url.parse(JSON.parse(meta).downloadUrl).hostname,
            method : 'GET',
            port : 443,
            path : url.parse(JSON.parse(meta).downloadUrl).path,
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN
            }
        }
        var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
        });
        request.end();
```

I have it working for NodeJS. Is there a way for me to achieve the file download in browser. I have a non-working piece of code using fetch at http://jsfiddle.net/LdyruLwv/

Comment: For 2. do you mean transfer encoding **chunked**?

Comment: yes indeed. I do mean transfer encoding chunked.

Comment: Okay, but why would that even matter?

Comment: I would have to iterate and join the chunked parts I guess, should be the reason for it to matter. Agreed it should not matter as long as I know the event getting fired on receipt of subsequent chunks.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read. I have edited the question to add my NodeJS code. if that helps clarify my intent.

Comment: By the way the servers in question is Google Drive in this case. However I have a similar problem on SFDC front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transfer encoding should be transparent to an application in a browser, don't worry about it.
Below is a basic ajax file download solution, it uses XHR2, blobs and anchors with download properties.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response); 
        var anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.download = 'filename.ext';
        anchor.href = blobUrl;
        anchor.click();
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', request_url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // Get a binary response
xhr.send(jData);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Musa. Appreciate your support very much.