# Downloading Excel file via aurelia-http-client

Tags: aurelia

I am working on a task, in which I have to download a report in xlsx format. The report file is generated successfully from server, and is received on client side (aurelia-http-client) as well but I don't know how to go further with downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30270714/6677648

... that would end up in something like a [response interceptor](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/3) in Aurelia like this:

```
        .withResponseType('blob')
        .withInterceptor({
            response(message) {
                var defaultFileName = "default.txt";
                var disposition = message.headers.headers['content-disposition']?message.headers.headers['content-disposition']:message.headers.headers['Content-Disposition'];
                if (disposition) {
                    var match = disposition.match(/.*filename=\"?([^;\"]+)\"?.*/);
                    if (match[1])
                        defaultFileName = match[1];
                }
                defaultFileName = defaultFileName.replace(/[<>:"\/\\|?*]+/g, '_');
                if (navigator.msSaveBlob)
                    return navigator.msSaveBlob(message.response, defaultFileName);
                var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(message.response);
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.download = defaultFileName;
                anchor.href = blobUrl;
                document.body.appendChild(anchor);
                anchor.click();
                document.body.removeChild(anchor);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the [downloadjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) library. Install the library, add it to your `aurelia.json` and then add

```
import * as download from 'downloadjs'
```

Then write your code as follows:

```
this.httpClient.fetch('your/url/here')
  .then((response: Response) => response.blob())
  .then((blob: Blob) => download(blob, 'filename.extension', 'mime type of the file'));
```

And voila, your file will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Helo with .withInterceptor() was generated errors in the response, change it to fix the error in no responce and unload multiple files simultaneously.

```
getLogsCsv(param) {
    this.http.configure(config => {
        config
            .withResponseType('blob');
    });
    return this.http.get("/admin/api/logs" + param)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                var defaultFileName = "FileName.csv";
                var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.response);
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.download = defaultFileName;
                anchor.href = blobUrl;
                document.body.appendChild(anchor);
                anchor.click();
                document.body.removeChild(anchor);
                return response.content;
            } else {
                console.log('response was not ok.');
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```